# Iterating over JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a single-line JSON file I'm trying to iterate over and looking for the best way to loop through it.

Exploded out, it looks something like:

```
{
 "system": "Test",
 "Continents": [
    {
        "Continent": {
            "name": "Europe",
            "location": "North"
         },
        "Continent": {
            "name": "Australia",
            "location": "South"
         },
        "Continent": {
            "name": "Asia",
            "location": "North"
         }
     }  
  ]
}
```

To start, I'm loading in the JSON with the following, which successfully loads the full JSON.

```
File.open(json_file, 'r') do |file|

    file.each do |line|            

      JSON.parse(line).each do |item|

        ## CODE TO ITERATE HERE

      end        
    end
 end
```

What I'm not sure how to do is to loop through the `Continents` section and pull the associated records. The goal would be to loop through and output the info in a list/table/display.

Thanks for the help - let me know if I can clarify at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSON.parse` will convert your JSON string to a Ruby hash, so you can work with it as you would any other:

```
json = JSON.parse(line)
json["Continents"].each do |continent|
  # do something
end
```

There is a separate problem with your data, however.  If you actually use `JSON.parse` with the data you posted, you should wind up with a result like this:

```
{"system"=>"Test", "Continents"=>[{"Continent"=>{"name"=>"Asia", "location"=>"North"}}]}
```

You'll notice there is only one continent - that's because Ruby hashes only support one value per key, so the `Continent` key is being overwritten for each `Continent` in the JSON. You might need to look at a different way of formatting that data.

Comment: This worked great - thanks. I don't follow your note about the dropping off of keys, as I can iterate through my JSON file just fine. Might just not have run into that issue yet. Thanks for the help @BaronVonBraun