# Rails 4 - Parsing and iterating through Google Places API JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-places-api, get-request

Using Rails 4 with the http gem to make simple get requests. I am hitting googles api with a url and a couple of parameters in order to return all nearby stadiums in json.

My goal here is to iterate through all of the different stadium results and pull out the photo_reference.

I am able to pull out the photo_reference from the first array like so:

```
def nearby_places(lat, long)
  response = HTTP.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=mykey&location=#{lat},#{long}&radius=3000&types=stadium")
  parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  parsed_response["results"][0]["photos"][0]["photo_reference"]
end
```

But I am having trouble iterating through and pulling out all photo references if multiple stadiums are returned. What is the best way to go about this?

Here is an example response from Google.

```
{    "html_attributions" : [],    "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.2285419,
               "lng" : -110.9488008
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "09b3cd5bd149c550db4740a67671b1d33b008531",
         "name" : "Arizona Stadium",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1371,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108405732138529965447/photos\"\u003eGoogle one\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAALCkhLHgNGOfNExFwmbdFw4vg_J5iWBomKOCh-HgF8ggTMiymuqUvSW7hSpfOjbcQ4iS6jUHf3lWTqzNHYF4b6gtq06ik9MKMCrGjDQgn70vrItbHHBGpHZ77wk8yVCPtEhB9D3W_Kn1W214cqoiRSwZsGhSlMG2x44K3CqOIbgUu-5a_KnGKbg",
               "width" : 2054
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJs_Gb76px1oYRPAYW8gEqUC4",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "rating" : 3.8,
         "reference" : "CnRiAAAAcUcY_BnrsZ4Ik9MI7W53JtIvHxVAvvl7lDl1vOkGCQ3uYwOpoR6OYp1cRNkS7LLACJv1Nc_HQjMeu7AIOm1H-9ciunC5Xl6M79wHZ7MB7n1NiQ4GD1HkCxoDTqoBx_qXx3czLkRYG31WSvtUMBNu3hIQzzQK_tSjvMMefqSuNzl3whoUz5o8eZbHCewDHXU7_Pig0bx_w4w",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1 National Championship Drive, Tucson"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.2301948,
               "lng" : -110.9460055
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "33aa72ea7a9688ca20333c774ecbbc0f4b29eedc",
         "name" : "McKale Memorial Center",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2132,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102117061543892797349/photos\"\u003eJohn Saunders\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAcM0Q5qsRVvptq77wWhfth_hkITyu1bd8jMdJWwDHNqQgb-IAExfc67QJTJU0XCDZ8MnXbLwcfa0lWfoTJT8K051_VsmT-CBS00Na40rL-MglE10RMs4sQBXCOAzkyoqzEhCXc9pTCQvp_DtQDvr0HjU_GhTbWyvV14IraM7osdnYkb2R4cebEQ",
               "width" : 3097
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJDwAsG6tx1oYRjFkokCR3jWY",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "rating" : 4,
         "reference" : "CnRpAAAAEAbkIN4gKquA3i2IC0vS4c8K7erBkDTyB6Z3eIEX4u4W3uMBQSgaOeySEOTVng2oIT1pWa1KsIpWqLSYaFVJDhaS800FEEBno5W0Me-TBy7qStmOMFO_jpeQ4iltCrds3enAtMgM9uQNoEPe8ntjtRIQ-lW3pOaDSJ1R4V5RS5UXNBoUF8OhthXnVaCSf6V3nxEFSNBlQ_s",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1 National Championship Drive, Tucson"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.2135012,
               "lng" : -110.9189719
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "d387dca1054f23d5a8767f03f9bb9f7b04f6363c",
         "name" : "Hi Corbett Field",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2048,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104635440524137932181/photos\"\u003eJose Olmos\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAV1gOFNPOQG-xqMMwhYiFt-p8go-4HXJWtAScAVYSuresCzbOdpz5x5dSMSAc2zlxNVtE_6JzwXKY4OG0ScY-QCEEs5t6XIqAfkcjf8CEqm4vLmkvdJ2Gxi0MbXDkSqwgEhAoCxH8BddGX41yTSh6i6U8GhQpdxiX-S9YVBchYzttaCAbhphbBg",
               "width" : 1536
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJB3zRTjxw1oYRxg2TEV6XwA8",
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAAg-sLDnKo_p9oI52MaNlzBBA2dCn874cSwE-Hxxl5dEjOu1HVIGcqXboWQxmVR44GUwgahIMa8XKdEarPggMgBl8eCDWb71u85pjRm8-j-JUuokKq_sxqfjcNf7KnbeM7bb4vl2Soz5vx5wI30udRUBIQOCz6nPaUc6cCGJ7Hi5vCfBoU7aFJXLr2tDCTBos1_3AWwPpqHEY",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "700 South Randolph Way, Tucson"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.2332841,
               "lng" : -110.9488008
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "a911fe55eaff462d3908c8fea14686f6591660d6",
         "name" : "Arizona Wildcats",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ____k6lx1oYR5ZkM9y--p6Y",
         "reference" : "CnRkAAAA7_fi19QO-sax4_ksm1jRDgGaO9nVNucqo9cCYL8JtwVkt3k_0i0J25QC9AhgkxMHrnPUcNHHtsda_wCqRSDBFUdmaBAmMX4jxE8WUBw-35rxcOoDHpGqftt-wlgLYUgn1JDJP9-Awe03b1hhHbWHwBIQYQIlDlKYKtIKdHRQfuVi7hoUh0w6evypLyiF1GCPy9zuFhuD5R0",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Tucson"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.2291294,
               "lng" : -110.9470374
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "28b19ac3c12af2a0de83694b851a1627c6458ad6",
         "name" : "MC Kaltr",
         "place_id" : "ChIJY7koG6tx1oYR5la-CtsxnbA",
         "reference" : "CmRcAAAAZ3bqbYMAtgcG3poewZ0t_7blrOgDXn6oE-e1UyevY6m_lxK7CLSc0MwTsi7m5t-fNUqlrmd-H_kyimy_caYyzrxki5iX580Vu3S5ttBUcTdjbWtjg1v8dy2HiPcLIPU4EhCh52vDSrwqlIbzsCqiliBbGhRipMYv__guCbPYKp1ja8uJkvurGg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1 National Championship Drive, Tucson"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.21510419999999,
               "lng" : -110.9384699
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "626eb52ef7968c58f0c8c4c9aca05bff1fc38962",
         "name" : "Drachman Stadium",
         "place_id" : "ChIJvc__01pw1oYRV9wdmSg4Pw8",
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAALn4CwTuCPfF0KkjO8nJl4k57eSovzcl5z4kjh6gf4UoC126lNyY1Lo-BNMvnFQjK3oPUb1Na5XvvM-BmmshaP2If19jiNdURUCCHftp6zw_2o8W0-ucOtvj4V0oi026dvZJMCFzu8YseLHmTjn5CDRIQenzfrkgA06wBd_4EoJb_eBoU-PESnLdv-4UMmR0SDQJ9P30lXNw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "stadium", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "the of 85719, 501 South Plumer Avenue, Tucson"
      }    ],    "status" : "OK" }
```

Comment: Maybe good list iteration on the response like this one [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363996/iterating-over-json-in-rails)